# I want to print the unique password and 19 random passwords from the txt file. How can I make this work?

Tags: python, generator, honeypot

```
from random import shuffle 
print('give me your password') 
password = input()
def generator():
    g = open('Desktop/COWRIE/passwords.txt', "r")
    passwords = g.read().split("\n")
    shuffle(passwords)
    g.close()
    txt = print ('YOUR HONEYPOT IS :','\n')
    for i in range(1,20):
        passwords[i]
        print(passwords[i])
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    generator()
```

Comment: Which is the unique password? I would assume that passwords from a text file will all be unique.

Comment: change `range(1, 20)` to `range(19)` if you want to `print` 19 passwords.

Comment: i edit it and now you can see the unique password. i mean 19 random passwords and the unique at the same time. that's what I want to make

Comment: Despite some problems with your code, I assume it does actually print 19 random passwords from the file. Is there something wrong as well?

Comment: my problem is that i want to print the 20 random passwords which does perfectly and one unique password that I give every time. this is my problem... i cant find out how to print all together

Comment: Which is the unique password?

Comment: This is how you will be able to input the unique password                                 
print('give me your password')
password = input()

Comment: So how were we supposed to know that? Please update your question with your real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean that you wanted to mix the user entered password with another 19 from a file?

```py
from random import shuffle 

def generator():
    password = input('give me your password: ')
    with open('Desktop/COWRIE/passwords.txt', "r") as g:
        passwords = g.read().split("\n")

    shuffle(passwords)
    passwords = passwords[:19]
    passwords.append(password)
    shuffle(passwords)

    print ('YOUR HONEYPOT IS :\n')
    for pw in passwords:
        print(pw)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    generator()
```

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can have a set and random index between 0 to len-1
then you can add to set random password until length of the set is 19

```
from random import shuffle, randrange

def generator():
    g = open('passwords.txt', "r")
    passwords = g.read().split("\n")
    shuffle(passwords)
    g.close()
    l =len(passwords)-1
    txt = print('YOUR HONEYPOT IS :', '\n')
    s =set()
    while len(s)<19:
        i = randrange(l)
        s.add(passwords[i])

    for p in passwords:
        print(p)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    generator()
```

Comment: how can i input a unique password and then print this with other 20 random passwords from the file?